# How note a wrong password with Python's UnRAR library?

Tags: python, exception, unrar

The following code (which tries to “open” an encrypted RAR-file supplying a wrong password):

```
from unrar import rarfile
import unrar 

try:
    rarfile.RarFile("encrypted.rar", pwd="wrong_password")
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
```

mostly, though nothing else is wrong with the RAR-file (can be decrypted without errors by using the correct password), outputs:

```
<class 'unrar.rarfile.BadRarFile'>
Invalid RAR file.
```

but sometimes it outputs:

```
<class 'RuntimeError'>
Bad password for Archive
```

How do I check if a password for a RAR-file is correct with Python's UnRAR library **without** chaining the exceptions?

In short: UnRAR library raises (randomly?) **different** exception for the **same type of error** (namely, wrong password supplied). In most of the cases it raises `BadRarFile` but sometimes it raises `RuntimeError`. Catching `RuntimeError` is bad enough (yet here we can at least check the `args`), but if one also catches `except unrar.rarfile.BadRarFile`, one cannot even differentiate between the error that (a) the password is wrong or (b) that the RAR-file is bad.

Comment: By catching `unrar.rarfile.BadRarFile`? If the library has custom exceptions, you can import them like any other class

Comment: @roganjosh if a wrong password is supplied, UnRAR library randomly (!) raises sometimes `unrar.rarfile.BadRarFile` and sometimes `RuntimeError`. The most specific I manage to get is `except (unrar.rarfile.BadRarFile, RuntimeError)` which is very bad.

Comment: Nothing is happening _randomly_. You can split the exception cases up, as was shown in the answer given. You're saying it's "very bad" to collect the 2 exceptions, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: @finefoot it _can't_ do this arbitrarily. The answer here would be to look at the source, but I'm not sure that this is what the OP is facing. Or, at least, asking about

Comment: @finefoot yes, that's the problem

Comment: To the source code it is, then. [Here](https://github.com/matiasb/python-unrar)

Comment: @roganjosh  it seems to depend on the version of the RAR-files which exception pops up

Comment: @finefoot god damn it, I anticipated that exact answer with `random` :P I don't think I have enough to go on to search the source, though. That's probably better left to the OP

Comment: @finefoot I get `RuntimeError` for the “newer” RAR files (v50), get `BadRarFile` for older ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain multiple `except` to narrow down the error. Unfortunately, your `unrar` library seems to raise the unspecific exception `RuntimeError` in case a bad password is provided. So you cannot be 100% sure if a bad password is the reason for the error.

```py
try:
    unrar.rarfile.RarFile("encrypted.rar", pwd="wrong_password")
except unrar.rarfile.BadRarFile:
    print("Specified file doesn't seem to be a proper RAR archive")
except RuntimeError:
    print("RuntimeError, possibly a wrong password")
except:
    print("Something else happened")
```

Other than using different error messages "Wrong password or defective file" and "Wrong password or something else", unfortunately, I don't see any possibility for improvement.

> In short: UnRAR library raises (randomly?) **different** exception for the **same type of error** (namely, wrong password supplied). In most of the cases it raises `BadRarFile` but sometimes it raises `RuntimeError`.

It's possible that depending on the version of the RAR file specs, there have been changes how a bad password is being handled. Maybe it isn't possible to differentiate between corrupt files and a wrong password with RAR files of a newer version while this was possible for older files. (Or the other way around.)

If the "original" `unrar` command doesn't have this issue, it's possibly a bug upstream in your Python wrapper library.

Comment: To make it clear, the problem is that it also sometimes (randomly!) raises `BadRarFile` instead of `RuntimeError` in the case of a valid encrypted RAR-File if a wrong password is supplied (valid means that the UnrRAR library **can itself** extract the RAR-file if the correct password is supplied).